# How do I add in a "range of years" to my Case Statement

Tags: mysql, case, date-arithmetic

How do I add in a "range of years" to my Case Statement below? I just need to fix the "INTERVAL 6 YEAR" & "INTERVAL 5 YEAR" criteria.

Here is the criteria I need to model:

If 1~5 years, then 11

If 6~10 years, then 14

If 11+ years, then 18

```
CASE WHEN hiredate < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 11 YEAR)
 THEN '18'
 WHEN hiredate < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 YEAR)
 THEN '14'
 WHEN hiredate < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
 THEN '11'
 ELSE '0'    END AS Non_Management_Accrual
```

Comment: Change `INTERVAL 5 YEAR` to `INTERVAL 1 YEAR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF` method to calculate number of days between two days and divide it by 365 to get `years`. Based on these, you can write up the `case` statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 1
 THEN '0'
 WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 6
 THEN '11'
 WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 11
 THEN '14'
 ELSE '18'    
 END AS Non_Management_Accrual
 FROM emp;
```

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35bea/6/0).

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Darshan, looking at it from a day perspective will give me more options going forward, and worked great!

One more question: I may need a second CASE statement if the employee is Management (If 1~5 years, then 14 and If 6+ years, then 18)

- I store a field in the same tblUsers called "reportsToID" which is the ID of the Manager.

Comment: Here is my query to get the Managers only, along with their ID, but how do I JOIN it to the previous query? SELECT COUNT(e.username) as employeeCount, m.username as reports_to, m.id
FROM tblusers e
INNER JOIN tblusers m on e.reportsToID = m.ID
GROUP BY m.username

Comment: Could you please add this to the question? I will update my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Darshan, I ended up creating Views on the MySQL side then adding the view into FROM statement of your code above. This gave me the correct output. Thanks.

```
<!--- Create the Manager Monthly Accruals (Mgt) dataset --->
  <cfquery name="rsLeaveTimeManagerAccruals" datasource="care">
SELECT    username, status, active, email, hiredate, tblUsers.picture AS eP
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hiredate, NOW()) AS year_passed
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 12 AS month_passed
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 365 AS day_passed
, CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hiredate, NOW())," years, ",TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 12," months, ",TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, hiredate, NOW()) MOD 365," days") AS EmployLengthActive
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hiredate, NOW()) AS monthly_accrual_time

, CASE WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 1
 THEN '0'
 WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) <= 5
 THEN '14'
 WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) >= 6
 THEN '18'
 END AS Management_Accrual


FROM      v_reports_to_mgt_list LEFT OUTER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.ID = v_reports_to_mgt_list.id
WHERE     clr_accrual = '1' AND hiredate  IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  hiredate
</cfquery>
```

Comment: One more thing: How to alter this line to be "2 months" instead of "1 year"?   "WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 1
 THEN '0'

Comment: @DarshanMehta, One more thing: How to alter this line to be "2 months" instead of "1 year"? "WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), hiredate) / 365) < 1 THEN '0'